# What is the smallest float number (the farthest from zero)

Tags: floating-point, numbers, precision

What is the smallest float number (the farthest from zero) that we can represent with precision ?
i googled the question but the answers Values are in floating point and denormalized number ..
So what is the answer .. and how do I calculate it ??
Is it -2^w or what ?

Comment: What do you mean by "represent with precision"?  What is wrong with using floating point to represent a "float number"?  What is wrong with denormalized numbers?  What is *w*?

Comment: Not all float numbers are equal to the actual number for example : 0.2 is not 0.2 in float because it is not a power of 2

Comment: 0.75 isn't a power of 2 either, but it can be represented exactly.

Comment: 0.75 is (2^-2) + (2^-2) +( 2^-2)

Comment: Which is not a power of 2; it is the sum of 3 powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

With IEEE-754 binary32, also called “single precision” and commonly used for the `float` type, the “smallest” representable number that is “farthest from zero” is −∞ (negative infinity).

The smallest finite representable number is −2<sup>128</sup>+2<sup>104</sup> = −340282346638528859811704183484516925440. This is because the maximum exponent in this format is 127 and the maximum representable significand is, in binary, 1.1111…1111<sub>2</sub>, where there are 24 1s in total, and 1.1111…1111<sub>2</sub> = 2−2<sup>−23</sup>, and 2<sup>127</sup>•(2−2<sup>−23</sup>) = 2<sup>128</sup>−2<sup>104</sup>, and the negative of that is −2<sup>128</sup>+2<sup>104</sup>.

The least magnitude representable numbers that are not zero are 2<sup>−149</sup> and its negation, −2<sup>−149</sup>. This is because the minimum exponent is −126 and the minimum significand that is not zero is 0.0000…0001<sub>2</sub>, which equals 2<sup>−23</sup>, and 2<sup>−126</sup>•2<sup>−23</sup> = 2<sup>−149</sup>.

Comment: Thank you ! But why the smallest number is -2^31 .. which is 1000000....000 in binary ?

Comment: @mohamadmahajne: There is no −2^31 in my answer. −2^31 is not a number of any particular note in IEEE-754 binary32. The bits 1000…000 represent −0. Mathematically that equals +0; they are only distinguished for the benefit of software specially designed to work with very small numbers in certain circumstances.

Comment: Oh sorry i meant is not * , but thank you I understand now !!